# c# Web mvc Enviar PDF sem salvar em disco e enviar por email

Tags: c#, mvc, pdf, email

Olá, tenho uma aplicação web MVC e tenho um método para enviar um e-mail e tenho que adicionar um PDF que é dinâmico, tenho que anexar ele nesse e-mail sem salvar no disco.

Alguém poderia ajudar?

Comment: Compartilhe o código do e-mail e da geração do PDF.

Comment: Podemos ajudar, mas qual a dúvida exatamente? Já tentou alguma coisa, usar um `Stream` por exemplo?

Comment: Acabei de conseguir enviar o pdf

Answer (score 0):

//Método de geração do pdf em memória

```
public static MemoryStream ArquivoTemporario()
    {
            HtmlToPdfBuilder builder = new HtmlToPdfBuilder(PageSize.LETTER);
            HtmlPdfPage page1 = builder.AddPage();

            string imagem = string.Empty;

            string titulo = "CONVOCAÇÃO DO FÓRUM";
            string txtparticipante = string.Empty;
            string txtconvidado = string.Empty;

            page1.AppendHtml("<table>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<thead>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<tr>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<th colspan='4'></th>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<th colspan='4'></th>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<th colspan='4' style='text-align: right;'>" + imagem + "</th>");
            page1.AppendHtml("</tr>");
            page1.AppendHtml("</thead>");
            page1.AppendHtml("</table>");

            page1.AppendHtml("<h2 align='center'><b><i>Relatório</i></b> </h2>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<br />");
            page1.AppendHtml("<table border='1'>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<thead>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<tr>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<th colspan='3'><strong>Tipo de Fórum:</strong> Duvidas</th>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<th><strong>Hora início</strong></th>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<th><strong>Hora término</strong></th>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<th><strong>Data</strong></th>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<th colspan='2'><strong>Local</strong></th>");
            page1.AppendHtml("</tr>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<tr>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<td colspan='3'><strong>Número de Fórum:</strong> </td>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<td> 00:00 </td>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<td> 00:00 </td>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<td>01/01/2018</td>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<th colspan='2'>Amazon</th>");
            page1.AppendHtml("</tr>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<tr>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<td colspan='4'><strong>Coordenador:</strong> Ana </td>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<td colspan='4'><strong>Secretário:</strong> Ana </td>");
            page1.AppendHtml("</tr>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<thead>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<tr colspan='8'>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<td><strong>Convidados:</strong> Ana </td>");
            page1.AppendHtml("</tr>");
            page1.AppendHtml("</thead>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<thead>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<tr colspan='8'>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<td><strong>Participantes:</strong> Ana </td>");
            page1.AppendHtml("</tr>");
            page1.AppendHtml("</thead>");


            page1.AppendHtml("<tr bgcolor='#E6E6FA'>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<td colspan='8'><strong>Descrição</strong></td>");
            page1.AppendHtml("</tr>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<tr>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<td colspan='8'> Descrição </td>");
            page1.AppendHtml("</tr>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<tr bgcolor='#E6E6FA'>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<td colspan='4'><strong>Pautas a serem apresentadas/discutidas.</strong></td>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<td colspan='2'><strong>Responsável</strong></td>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<td colspan='2'><strong>Duração</strong></td>");
            page1.AppendHtml("</tr>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<tr colspan='8'>");
            page1.AppendHtml("</tr>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<tr bgcolor='#E6E6FA'>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<td colspan='3'><strong>Pendências</strong></td>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<td colspan='1'><strong>Responsável</strong></td>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<td colspan='1'><strong>Prazo inicial</strong></td>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<td colspan='1'><strong>Prazo final</strong></td>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<td colspan='2'><strong>Status</strong></td>");
            page1.AppendHtml("</tr>");
            page1.AppendHtml("<tr colspan='8'>");
            page1.AppendHtml("</tr>");
            page1.AppendHtml("</tbody>");
            page1.AppendHtml("</table>");
            builder.AddStyle("th", "font-size: 10px;");
            builder.AddStyle("td", "font-size: 10px;");

            byte[] file = builder.RenderPdf();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

            MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream(file);

            pdfStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);


            return pdfStream;
    }
```

//Método para enviar o e-mail

```
public void EnviarEmail(string destinatario, string sub, string body)
{
            try
            {
String path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();

string server = path + "Content\\Uploads\\Email\\";

                MemoryStream pdfConvocacao = Email.ArquivoTemporario();

                string cabecalho = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CabecalhoEmail"];
                string remetenteEmail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Email"];
                string senha = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Senha"];
                string dataHoraInicial = "";
                string dataHoraFinal = "";
                string agenda = "Agenda.ics";
                string schLocation = "";
                string schSubject = "";
                string schDescription = "";

                System.DateTime schBeginDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dataHoraInicial);
                System.DateTime schEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dataHoraFinal);

                String[] contents = { "BEGIN:VCALENDAR",
                              "PRODID:-//Flo Inc.//FloSoft//EN",
                              "BEGIN:VEVENT",
                              "DTSTART:" + schBeginDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMdd\\THHmmss\\Z"), 
                              "DTEND:" + schEndDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMdd\\THHmmss\\Z"), 
                              "LOCATION:" + schLocation, 
                              "DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:" + schDescription,
                              "SUMMARY:" + schSubject, "PRIORITY:3", 
                              "END:VEVENT", "END:VCALENDAR" };

                System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(server + agenda, contents);
                Attachment mailAttachment = new Attachment(server + agenda);
                MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
                mailMessage.To.Add(destinatario);
                mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(remetenteEmail, "Instituto Empresariar", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                mailMessage.Subject = sub;
                mailMessage.Body = cabecalho + "<h3>" + body + "</h3>";
                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High;
                mailMessage.Attachments.Add(mailAttachment);

                byte[] bytes = pdfConvocacao.ToArray();
                pdfConvocacao.Close();

                mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(bytes), "Convocação.pdf"));

                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(remetenteEmail, senha);
                smtp.Port = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PortaEmail"]);
                smtp.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostEmail"];
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(mailMessage);

                mailAttachment.Dispose();
                mailMessage.Dispose();
                DeletaArquivo(server, agenda);
                DeletaArquivo(server, "Convocação.pdf");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: Olá Carol. Seria interessante se você pudesse explicar como esses métodos funcionam e como eles podem ser implementados, desta forma você facilitaria mais o entendimento para os usuários que estiver passando pelo mesmos problemas.